# node.js create and/or append to file

Tags: node.js

Using node.js I'm creating a function to update a file that contains a JSON list by appending a new element to the list. The updated list is rewritten back to the file. If the file doesn't exist I create it.

Below, `__list_append(..)` does the list append and file update.

My question is if (and should) I can restructure this code to not have two calls to `__list_append`. I'm a bit new to node.js, and don't have a good feel for the asynchronous tactics.

```
function list_append(filename, doc) {
  fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
    if (exists) {
      fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
        if (err)
          throw err;
        __list_append(filename, JSON.parse(data), doc);
      });
    } else
      __list_append(filename, [], doc);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to get a bit pedantic with "best practices," but when I'm writing code and I get a gut feeling that something's not right or that something could be changed, I go over some well known best practices and attempt to see if the code I'm writing adheres to them. [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), while being principles of object oriented programming, can be useful to think about in other contexts. In this case, it seems to me that the function is violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Single_Responsibility_Principle):

> One of the most foundational principles of good design is:
>
> > Gather together those things that change for the same reason, and separate those things that change for different reasons.
>
> This principle is often known as the Single Responsibility Principle or SRP. In short, it says that a subsystem, module, class, or even a function, should not have more than one reason to change.

(This could perhaps be exchanged for [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) or other similar principles for this example, but the concept is the same.)

In this case, the function has two responsibilities: (1) getting the current (or default) list associated with a filename, and (2) appending data to said list. A first pass at separating these concerns might look something like this:

```
function get_current_list(filename, callback) {
  fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
    if (exists) {
      fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
        if (err)
          return callback(err);
        callback(null, JSON.parse(data));
      });
    } else
      callback(null, []);
  });
}

function list_append(filename, doc) {
  get_current_list(filename, function(err, list) {
    if(err) throw err;
    __list_append(filename, list, doc);
  });
}
```

Now, `get_current_list` is *only* responsible for getting the current list in a file (or an empty array if there is no file), and `__list_append` is (assumed to be) *only* responsible for appending to it; `list_append` is now a simple integration point between these two functions. The functions are a bit more reusable and can also be tested more easily (as an aside, a test-first or TDD approach to programming can help you notice these kinds of things up front). Furthermore, repeating `callback` in `get_current_list` is quite a bit more generic than repeating `__list_append`; if you need to change `__list_append` to something else, it now is only called in one place.

Comment: I'm kind of new to nodejs - where is __list_append defined, is it a typo for list_append ?

Comment: I think it's a custom function written by Noah, from the question: "Below, `__list_append(..)` does the list append and file update." It's basically a black box for the purposes of this question.

Answer (score 0):

This case always feels unsatisfying to me because yes, you do have to repeat your call to `__list_append` on both branches because only one of the branches is synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I like and up voted Brandon's answer, but this also works:

`function list_append(filename, doc) {
  fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
    var data = [];
    if (exists) {
      data = fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf8");
    }
    __list_append(filename, data, doc);
  });
}`